# Which program do you highly suggest for google extension silent install?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, inno-setup, nsis, silent-installer, advanced-installer

I have tried to use http://www.extuper.com/ but unfortunately it didn't work on building.

There are some programs but i am not sure which is most proper for converting chrome extention file to executable one. (NSIS / INNO / Advanced Installer etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Both Chrome and Firefox have been reducing support for silent extensions because of the amount of spyware and other junk.

You should just add your extension to the official store...

Comment: I just need to save it as an exe file. Not for distrubuting purpose.

Comment: Why? What is the point of putting a browser extension in a exe file? The browser developers ONLY want people to install extensions from the official store.

Comment: You can only install an extension (via registry) that _is_ already in the Store.

Comment: To add a source to my comment above, http://chrome.blogspot.ch/2014/05/protecting-chrome-users-from-malicious.html

Answer (score 0):

NSIS and Inno Setup are free (even open source) and easy to learn.

Pick one (Inno Setup if you have Delphi/Pascal experiences) and you can create installer in a few minutes.